# Katalon test execution failing from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

Repository code https://github.com/katalon-studio-samples/katalon-web-automation fails with chained exceptions java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/lightbody/bmp/BrowserMobProxy and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebElement

It works within shell with command
`/home/prakash/personalreason/Katalon_Studio_Linux_64-6.2.2/./katalon -noSplash -data=/home/prakash/katalon  -runMode=console -consoleLog -projectPath="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/katalon-web-automation/Katalon Web Tutorial.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/New Test Suite" -browserType="Chrome (headless)"`

My jenkins' execute shell reads

```
#export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
Xvfb :0 >& /dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:0

sudo chmod 777 .
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/katalon-web-automation/bin
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/katalon-web-automation/Libs


/home/prakash/personalreason/Katalon_Studio_Linux_64-6.2.2/./katalon -noSplash -data=/home/prakash/katalon  -runMode=console -consoleLog -projectPath="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/katalon-web-automation/Katalon Web Tutorial.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/New Test Suite" -browserType="Chrome (headless)"
```

Expected result

```
2019-07-25 18:14:03.291 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor  - --------------------
2019-07-25 18:14:03.292 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor  - END Test Suites/New Test Suite
2019-07-25 18:14:03.292 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor  - ====================
Launcher status after execution process completed: Running
Start writing execution.uuid file to folder: /home/prakash/personalreason/katalon-web-automation/Reports/New Test Suite/20190725_175941
For real-time monitoring and better reporting capabilities please integrate this project with Katalon Analytics (more details at https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-analytics/docs/integration-with-katalon-studio.html#enable-integration)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Suites/New Test Suite - Chrome (headless) - 20190725_175941.....38/38(100%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actual result

````
Test Suites/New Test Suite - Chrome (headless) - 20190725_191630........1/38(3%)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019-07-25 19:16:31.767 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/Custom Keyword Dropdown Values Verification/DropDown_Values_Alphabetical Order FAILED.
Reason:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebElement
    at DropDown_Values_Alphabetical Order.run(DropDown_Values_Alphabetical Order:10)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:133)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:116)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:83)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1564062390358.run(TempTestSuite1564062390358.groovy:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at Script1502810910022.run(Script1502810910022.groovy:10)
    ... 13 more

Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/lightbody/bmp/BrowserMobProxy
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/lightbody/bmp/BrowserMobProxy
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.postExecution(TestCaseExecutor.java:193)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:258)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:133)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:116)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:83)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:157)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1564062390358.run(TempTestSuite1564062390358.groovy:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy
    ... 8 more
Build step 'Execute Katalon Studio Tests' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE```
````